# "the prime factorization of an element, if it exists, is always unique"

Tags: ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Why exactly? I'm seeing this in proofs that a ring is a UFD, but it's not jumping out from the ideal definition of primality.

Comment: Most see the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and a proof, in elementary number theory, before they see acronyms like UFD or the words "ideal" and "ring."

Comment: I don't typically remember many proofs...

Comment: *but it's not jumping out from the ideal definition of primality* ... and it shouldn't. There isn't any implicational relationship between definitions of primality and prime factorization of an element. There are domains which have primes but also have elements without factorizations, and it's possible that even though they have factorizations they are not unique. It's just that this factorization behavior characterizes UFDs.

Comment: factorisations into irreducibles, do you mean? Or degenerate rings?

Answer (score 3):

Note: My proof uses the assumption that $R$ is an Integral Domain (in particular is commutative).

Suppose $a=p_1 p_2...p_n$ for primes $p_i \in R$.  We show this prime factorization is unique.

Suppose $q_1 q_2 ...q_m$ is another prime factorization of $a$. $q_1$ divides $p_i$ for some $1\leq i \leq n$.  To see this, note that $q_1$ divides $p_1 (p_2 ... p_n)$ implies $q_1$ divides $p_1$ or $(p_2 ... p_n)$.  If is divides $p_1$ we are done, if not it divides $(p_2 ... p_n)$, etc.

We have $q_1|p_i$, i.e., $p_i=xq_1$ for some $x\in R$.  If $p_i$ divides $x$ then you will get $yq_1=1$ for some $y\in R$ implying $q_1$ is a unit, contradiction. (Note, you need $R$ to be an integral domain for this argument to work). So $p_i|q_1$.

Thus $p_i$ and $q_1$ are associates.  Equivalently $q_1=up_i$ for some unit $u\in R$. Now you can factor $p_i$ to get $p_i(p_1p_2 ...p_{i-1}p_{i+1}... p_n-uq_2q_3...q_n)=0$.  Again using the assumption that $R$ is an integral domain, you have $p_1p_2 ...p_{i-1}p_{i+1}... p_n=uq_2q_3...q_m$. Rinse and repeat.

This way you cross off associates on each side of $p_1...p_n=q_1...q_m$ in pairs.  In the end you must have $n=m$, else you get a unit with a prime factor.

Comment: Is the definition of prime as $p|ab \implies p|a$ always equivalent to the $ab \in <p> \implies a \in p$ definition?

Comment: @John Yes, those literally mean the same things (except you forgot the "or $p\mid b$" and "or $b\in(p)$" parts).

Comment: I did not really use that here, what you are saying is correct. because $x\in (a) \iff a|x$.

Comment: Oh yes I remember now, $<p>=pR$

Comment: @JohnFernley Please check my edit now to see if I did a better job explaining.

Comment: This is great. I've done the exam now mind